# Facebook FQL Distance paginate not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I wonder why this FQL query isnt working

```
SELECT page_id, name,type, distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") FROM place WHERE type="PLACE" AND 5000 < distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") ORDER BY distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") ASC LIMIT 10
```

But this one works

```
SELECT page_id, name,type, distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") FROM place WHERE type="PLACE" AND 5000 > distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") ORDER BY distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") ASC LIMIT 10
```

The difference is that in the second one im using greater than ">". But in the first one im using less than "<"

I want to paginate using facebook places distance.

Comment: it returns the error: `{"error": {"message": "(#606) Distance must be 0 for a greater than query.",  "type": "OAuthException",  "code": 606 } }`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. The reason I was doing this is because I want to paginate by distance. If you get the distance of your last result then you can paginate the next results using NOT() to exclude anything within 5000metres like this instead:

```
SELECT page_id, name,type, distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") FROM place WHERE type="PLACE" AND distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") < 50000   AND  NOT (page_id IN( SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE  distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") < 5000 )) ORDER BY distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your non-working example is trying to fetch places 5KM *or more* from the specified coordinates, which is almost every place on earth - The API simply won't return that much data to you.

I believe the Facebook API supports searching at most 50KM from a location

Comment: That's not correct because this also doesnt work `SELECT page_id, name,type, distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") FROM place WHERE type="PLACE" AND 5000 < distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") AND 10000 > distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227")` That is fetching places less than 10000 metres and more than 5000 metres

Comment: and the max for searching is 50000 metres. Facebook uses metres not kilometres

Comment: Why is that not correct? the example in your comment is trying to find places At least 5KM from the location and at most 10KM from the location; the API is going to ignore the first part entirely because you're trying to search too many places. 
Also, 50KM = 50000M.

If you're trying to find places between X and Y metres from a location, ask the API for places within Y metres and do the filtering yourself - FQL does not work like ANSI SQL, the underlying data doesn't support the type of query you're trying to construct

Comment: Ok, i think I know what you mean now. But why isn't this working then `SELECT page_id, name,type, distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") FROM place WHERE type="PLACE" AND  10000 > distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227") AND 5000 < distance(latitude, longitude, "37.7873589", "-122.408227")` switched them around so it first selects places that are within 10km, and from those return places greater than 5km in distance` lol you're right 50km is 50000 metres ;)  Must be losing my mind lol

Comment: Same answer, you simply can't do any query which has 'where distance() > X', it's not supported

Comment: Ok great thanks. I figured out a solution. I'm posting it in a sec